# Modify variable in for loop

Tags: swift

The code below would print `abc` 5 times and then print `1024`. As far as I understand, in any for, the "iterator " is automatically declared (the equivalent of a C(++)/Java `for(int i=1; i<=5; i++)` ). Is it possible to actually not automatically create that variable and use the one declared before the `for` so that it would print `abc` 5 times and then print `5`, thus modifying it?

```
var i = 1024
for i in 1...5 {
    print("abc")
}
print(i)
```

Comment: What is the output of `print(i)` inside the loop?

Comment: @ZoeCarver 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Comment: @ZoeCarver How exactly do you want this to work? What do you want to use the existing `i`, and have it overwrite the `1024` with 1, 2, ... eventually 5?

Comment: @Alexander I do not want to do anything specifically right now, but I am just curious to know if it can be done

Comment: @TomaRadu-Petrescu Well we can't answer a request for "nothing specifically"

Comment: @Alexander uhm ok. the answer is yes or no.

Comment: @TomaRadu-Petrescu It will be, once I can understand what exactly you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

@DrummerB's answer works, but if you want a for...in loop, this will also work. It's the same principle - declare your variable outside the loop and increment it inside it:

```
var i:Int = 0
for _ in 0...5 {
    print("abc")
    i += 1
}
print(i)
```

Since you aren't referencing a loop variable, Swift syntax recommends an underscore.

Answer (score 1):

You could just rewrite the for loop as a while loop like this:

```
var i = 1024
i = 1
while i <= 5 {
    print("abc")
    i = i+1
}
print(i)
```

Comment: What's the point of setting `i` to `1024` and then to `1`?

Comment: @rmaddy Demonstration. That's what a for loop would do as OP requested.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to change the value of the i using the loop in that way, you can do:

```
var i=1024
for j in 1...5 {
     print("abc")
     i = j
}
print(i)
```

The j would be used strictly in the loop, so once finished, it's value is dumped. But a variable declared before (i in your case), could take it's value and maintain it.